# How to create a StreamableTable which is also a ScannableTable (Apache Calcite)?

Tags: apache-calcite

I am looking to implement a `org.apache.calcite.schema.Table` which can be used as a stream as well as a table.

I was going through the Calcite documentation, and [here](https://calcite.apache.org/docs/stream.html#an-example-schema) it mentions an example of `Orders` table which is a stream as well as table. It also mentions that both of the following queries are applicable on this `Orders` table/stream,

```
SELECT STREAM * FROM Orders;
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM Orders;
```

I am trying to implement a class whose instances are such tables. I implemented the [StreamableTable](https://calcite.apache.org/javadocAggregate/org/apache/calcite/schema/StreamableTable.html) interface as well as the [ScannableTable](https://calcite.apache.org/javadocAggregate/org/apache/calcite/schema/ScannableTable.html) interface but still not able to get it to work both ways. When I try to execute a non-stream query (like `SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE`), I get the following error,

```
Caused by: org.apache.calcite.runtime.CalciteContextException: From line 1, column 15 to line 1, column 38: Cannot convert stream 'TEST_TABLE' to relation
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
at org.apache.calcite.runtime.Resources$ExInstWithCause.ex(Resources.java:467)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlUtil.newContextException(SqlUtil.java:883)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlUtil.newContextException(SqlUtil.java:868)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.newValidationError(SqlValidatorImpl.java:5043)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateModality(SqlValidatorImpl.java:3739)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateModality(SqlValidatorImpl.java:3664)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateQuery(SqlValidatorImpl.java:1048)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlSelect.validate(SqlSelect.java:232)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateScopedExpression(SqlValidatorImpl.java:1016)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validate(SqlValidatorImpl.java:724)
at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertQuery(SqlToRelConverter.java:567)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.Prepare.prepareSql(Prepare.java:242)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.Prepare.prepareSql(Prepare.java:208)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.CalcitePrepareImpl.prepare2_(CalcitePrepareImpl.java:642)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.CalcitePrepareImpl.prepare_(CalcitePrepareImpl.java:508)
at org.apache.calcite.prepare.CalcitePrepareImpl.prepareSql(CalcitePrepareImpl.java:478)
at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteConnectionImpl.parseQuery(CalciteConnectionImpl.java:231)
at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteMetaImpl.prepareAndExecute(CalciteMetaImpl.java:556)
at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaConnection.prepareAndExecuteInternal(AvaticaConnection.java:675)
at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaStatement.executeInternal(AvaticaStatement.java:156)
... 3 more
```

Queries like `SELECT STREAM * FROM TEST_TABLE` work as expected.

Can someone help me create such a table?

Answer (score 0):

The modality of `Select * FROM Orders` is `RELATION` but the table is an instance of `StreamableTable` and that's why the above exception is thrown. I changed the `RelOptTableImpl#supportsModality` a bit as follows.

```java
  @Override public boolean supportsModality(SqlModality modality) {
    switch (modality) {
    case STREAM:
      return table instanceof StreamableTable;
    default:
      // check whether the table is scannable 
      if (table instanceof ScannableTable) {
        return true;
      }
      return !(table instanceof StreamableTable);
    }
  }
```

For the above SQL, now the plans generated were as per usual:

Logical:

```java
LogicalProject(ROWTIME=[$0], ID=[$1], PRODUCT=[$2], UNITS=[$3])
  LogicalTableScan(table=[[STREAMS, ORDERS]])
```

Physical:

```java
EnumerableTableScan(table=[[STREAMS, ORDERS]])
```

With Result set starting with:

```java
ROWTIME=2015-02-15 10:15:00; ID=1; PRODUCT=paint; UNITS=10",
ROWTIME=2015-02-15 10:24:15; ID=2; PRODUCT=paper; UNITS=5"
```

You can create a test case for this in StreamTest with above changes.

Comment: so, does it mean that, we need to make changes in the calcite's code?

Comment: What would be the change to the `create table` statement to make a table work with `select stream from` queries?